# Customize OpenIddict Client Error Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, openiddict

How can you customize the error messages provided by the Openiddict client. The errors in the sample app are text only, and break the user experience.

Steps to replicate:

1. Clone the openiddict-samples repository `git clone https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples.git`
2. Start the Velusia.Client project (I use Visual Studio)
3. Browse to https://localhost:44338/callback/login/local

This displays a text only response:

```
error:missing_token
error_description:The security token is missing.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2000
```

How do you customize this response to show "proper" MVC view with an error message (similar to https://localhost:44338/error)?

I understand this is the correct response - I just want to customize how it is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm exploring solutions for this issue. I've devised a potential approach involving registering an event handler for the client within the Startup.cs, but I'm not entirely certain if it's the correct method. Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
                options.AddEventHandler<ProcessErrorContext>(builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseInlineHandler(context =>
                    {
                        if(context != null)
                        {
                            if(context.Error != null)
                            {
                                throw new Exception(context.Error);
                            }
                        }
   
                        return default;
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd recommend is to use [ASP.NET Core's native status code pages middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#usestatuscodepages) to render error pages: OpenIddict natively supports it and you can enable it quite easily:

```cs
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddClient(options =>
    {
        options.UseAspNetCore()
               .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
    });
```

See https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Client for an example.